# For a Xamarin Forms application how should I decide what goes in the App constructor or the OnStart()?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here's the code that I have:

```
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DB.CreateTables();
        DB.GetSettings();
        DB.PopulateTables();
        SetResourceColors();
        SetResourceDimensions();
        MainPage = new MainPage();
        activity = Helpers.Activity.Create();
        VersionTracking.Track();
        DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfoChanged += OnMainDisplayInfoChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {


    }
```

Can someone explain to me.  Is there any difference between me placing the code such as I have in the constructor or in the OnStart() method? What's the normal way to do this?

Comment: this is largely a matter of personal preference, although you cannot make async calls from a constructor, but you can in OnStart()

Answer (score 5):

I have been working with `Xamarin.Forms` for a long time now and this is how I and my fellow developers use the OnStart Method.

If you check the [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/app-lifecycle) documents it says the following about it :

> OnStart - Called when the application starts.

So, first of all, you should know that there is no specific use of the `OnStart` method, to be very honest there is no major difference in between using the constructor or this lifecycle method because both get called on XF framework startup, first the constructor then the `OnStart` method.

Now let's come to the differences.

As [Jason](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1338/jason) pointed out, the `OnStart` method is a lifecycle method and hence has a return type unlike the constructor, so you can even call an asynchronous piece of code in the `OnStart` method but you cannot do the same in the constructor as constructors cannot be asynchronous.

Which means if you have the below method:

```
public async Task<bool> IsSomeThingWorkingAsync(//SomeParams)
{
 // Code 
}
```

Now, this method cannot be asynchronously called from the constructor since constructors are forcefully synchronous and have no return types. But if you try doing that from the on start method it's quite easy and it will work. In this case, you use the OnStart method. Something like below:

```
 protected override async void OnStart()
    {
       bool WasWorkSuccess=await IsSomeThingWorkingAsync();
       //do something with the boolean
    }
```

A constructor is intended to be used for wiring. In the constructor, you want to avoid doing actual work. You basically prepare the class to be used. Methods are intended to do actual work.

**Note:** *There are no performance gains whatsoever by choosing one over the other - it's really a matter of preference and standard.*

Comment: good point. I deleted my comment as I see you did mention it already. If you want you can delete yours, then I'll delete this one. Hopefully we won't get into an infinite loop.

Comment: @AdamDiament Haha i like your sense of humour :)

Answer (score 4):

[Please go through the details here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/app-lifecycle)

You can write the initialisation codes in App() constructor. But you need to be very careful abut registering events.

Reason is,

For example in Android, If the app is launched and it is in task list and if you try to launch the app again by clicking on app icon. The constructor of App() will call again. This will register the event multiple times and will create issues.

So for events I will suggest you to use overriden methods for registering events.

Again as Jason pointed it out, It is your personal preference where to write your code.